# how to fetch message from wmq node serially in mule flow

Tags: mule

I have a flow in which I am using wmq to get message. But the message is coming randomly. I want to obtain it as first input first output. I am using thread to obtain message one by one.

I have one mule flow in which i am getting soap message from Queue using WMQ Endpoint. Let i have 8 message in the queue with the value of one field(for your reference) of soap message is 60,60,82,77,79,47,79 & 47 resp. But when i am fetching the queue in my flow, i am getting message in different sequence. e.q. first time i got the message in the sequence 77,82,60,60,79,47,79,47. Other time i got 60,60,77,79,47,79,47,82.

It is effecting my application. Please let me know how can i get the SOAP message in the FIFO sequence from WMQ.

You can check my xml of mule flow in this link How to make compatible wmq with java code in MULE

Here i have also used the processing strategy of flow which is allowing max 1 thread at a time(Not mentioned in the attached link for flow xml)

Comment: Mule ESB reads WMQ messages as they are found in WMQ, this is, as a FIFO queue. Is it possible that your messages are read in order and the output for your flows is what comes unordered? Can you provide more detail on your scenario?

Comment: i have added the detailed scenario in the question itself. Please check

Comment: Since I have applied queued asynchronous strategy, is it can affect the application. I am checking out the payload everytime and it is not in order